# random array for creating a test

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a test. Here's my table as php array:

```
/**
* Database `soru_arsivi`
*/

/* `soru_arsivi`.`cevaplar` */
$cevaplar = array(
array('cevap_id' => '1','cevap_icerik' => 'was','yanlis_cevaplar' => 
'wasn\'t / were / weren\'t'),
array('cevap_id' => '2','cevap_icerik' => 'wasn\'t','yanlis_cevaplar' => 
'was / were / weren\'t')
);
```

And my code to so far:

```
$cevaplar = "SELECT yanlis_cevaplar, cevap_icerik FROM cevaplar";
$cevap_sonuc = $conn->query($cevaplar) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$result = $cevap_sonuc->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$siklar = array_rand($result, 4);

foreach ($result as $siklar) {
echo "<li>a)" . $result[$siklar[0]] . "</li>";
echo "<li>b)" . $result[$siklar[1]] . "</li>";
echo "<li>c)" . $result[$siklar[2]] . "</li>";
echo "<li>d)" . $result[$siklar[3]] . "</li>";
}
```

The thing is I'm getting these error messages:

> Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the
>   number of elements in the array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appro\admin\sorularabak.php on line 59
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appro\admin\sorularabak.php on line 62
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appro\admin\sorularabak.php on line 62

What's wrong with it :)

Comment: `Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array` is a pretty solid message. Do you even have 4 entries in `$result`?

Comment: I have 3 arguments in yanlis_cevaplar (wrong_answers) and one in cevap_icerik (right answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
array_rand ( array $array [, int $num = 1 ] )
 $num
 Specifies how many entries should be picked.
```

I think you gets the number of rows in a result

```
$siklar = array_rand($result, mysqli_num_rows ($cevap_sonuc ));
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\appro\admin\sorularabak.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\appro\admin\sorularabak.php on line 63

It continues to give this error though.

Comment: i think you add if statements to check $cevap_sonuc .If it is null then don't use fetch_all or array_rand  (  if ( mysqli_num_rows ($cevap_sonuc ) >0) {$result = $cevap_sonuc->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$siklar = array_rand($result, 4);}